# Why does Laravel Nova return 404 on login only on production environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I´m using Laravel (10) with Nova (4.31). On my **development environment** I **can login to nova without issues** but on my **production environment login doesn´t work** - after clicking on "login" nothing happens (although the login screen is shown).

Network traffic shows, that the XHR request that is made by clicking on "login" returns a 404:

```
POST https://example.com/nova/login -> 404.
```

So I also had a look at the **registered routes** and also those are looking correct:

```
POST nova/login ..................... nova.login › Laravel\Nova › LoginController@login
```

At the moment I´ve no idea what might cause the problem. On my development enviroment everything works fine and there is no difference in the Nova configuration. There are also no additional layers in front of the production server like proxies or a CDN that might be the reason for that error.

So I´m wondering if you have any idea where I can start further investigations to find the reason for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error I´ve found the issue:
I use Laravel Forge for deployment and server management. There I´ve added a .htaccess rule to the /nova path. I didn´t investigate the nginx settings created behind the Forge UI but it looks like that GET authorization works but POST generates a 404...

I´ve disabled the security rule and now the login works as expected.